# PropertyChanged on base class without INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, inheritance, prism, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

Simple question, but struggling with the solution...

I have a base class. It is NOT possible to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in this base class.

I'm using MVVM (prism) and my VM contains a ObservableCollection.
This ObservableCollection is the itemsSource of a Datagrid.

The Question is: when I change a cell in the Datagrid, how can I notify my VM that (and which) property has changed?

Thanks!

Edit: added code

The base class:

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The VM property:

```
private ObservableCollection<BaseClass> mycollection

public ObservableCollection<BaseClass> MyCollection
{
   get
   {
      return mycollection
   }
   set
   {
      SetProperty(ref mycollection, value);
   }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<DataGrid          
   AutoGenerateColumns="False"
   CanUserAddRows="False"
   GridLinesVisibility="None"
   ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"                      
   SelectionMode="Single">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Value">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBox Text="{Binding Value,  Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>  
   </DataGrid.Columns>                  
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Bindings will automatically update the value in binded object's property. Share your binding and sample code if it's not happening.

Comment: Please share some code so that we can understand your particular infrastructure and situation better. This is also important to help find a solution..

Comment: whose base is your base class? the vm's? the item's? the collection's? if you want an item to notify your vm, you can use whatever mechanism you like, if you want to notify the ui via binding, you're stuck with `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @Sham code added

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow code added

Comment: @Haukinger The base class cannot implement INPC

Comment: This might be a [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)... why exactly can the base class not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow The base class is from another assembly which is not mine

Answer (score 0):

Create a "facade", e.g. create a model that has identical properties but also inherits from INPC. When a property "Name" on the facade changes, set the value to the "base class" object and also call INPC.

```
public class BaseClass { public string Name { get; set; } }

public class FacadeBaseClasse : INotifyPropertyChanged //Facade that implements INPC interface
{
    private readonly BaseClass baseC;
    public string Name
    {
        get => baseC.Name;
        set 
        {
            baseC.Name = value;
            OnPropertyChange();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are a lot of "model" classes... Building a facade (which would be the same except the INPC) is double code just for that

Comment: I think this is an implication of MVVM. Tell me if you find a way around this with less code. @Haukinger also had some alternatives but they all come with notable performance hits

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `<TextBox Text="{Binding Value,  Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />` is a typo and you mean `Binding Name`, and expanding on my comment above:

If you want to notify the data grid (that is, the cell's text box) of a change done to the `Name` of an item in your collection, you **must** implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (unless you raise a change for the entire collection, which your users will not like, because it will - at least - reset scrolling).

If you want to notify the rest of your app when your user changes the `Name` of an item by clicking on its cell and typing something, you're completely free in your choice of messaging mechanism. Of course, modifying `BaseClass.Name` is preferred with options like

- `INotifyPropertyChanged` (can be used by services, too, it's not limited to the ui)
- a classic .net event, e.g. `event Action<object,NameChangedEventArgs` NameChanged`
- `IEventAggregator`, e.g. `_eventAggregator.GetEvent<NameChangedEvent>().Publish( new NameChangedEventArgs( this, newName, oldName ) )`

In case you absolutely cannot modify `BaseClass`, you can create a watcher that sits around and periodically checks all items he knows of and compare their current names with the last known state and then do one of the above in case it detects a change. This is not the most efficient solution, though, because you have to register all your items and either unregister them or use weak references (that add additional overhead).